# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, tomcat, sockets, socketexception, objectinputstream

I have an application with client server architecture. The client 
use Java Web Start with Java Swing / AWT and the sert uses HTTP server / Servlet with 
Tomcat. 
The communication is made from the serialization of objects, create a 
ObjectOutput serializes a byte array and send to the server 
respectively called the ObjectInputStream and deserializes.

The application follows communicating correctly to a certain 
time of concurrency where starting to show error 
"SocketException read timeout". The erro happens  when the server invoke the method 
ObjectInputStream.getObject() in my servlet doPost method.

The tomcat will come slow and the errors start to decrease server response time until the crash time where i must restart the server and after everything works.

Someone went through this problem ?

Client Code

```
URLConnection conn =  url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oss = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

oss.writeUTF("protocol header sample");

oss.writeObject(_parameters);
oss.flush();
oss.close();
```

Server Code

```
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(_request.getInputStream());
String method = input.readUTF();

parameters = input.readObject();
```

input.readObject() is where the error is

Comment: Is the amount of time that passes before the SocketException 20 mins or longer? (if I recall the standard amount of time a tcp/ip socket will wait before it times out if there is no connect activity) ? After all the Exception is telling you "read timeout" also might this have something to do with asynchronous nature of the web?

Comment: It's a tcp linux parameter? Like buffer mem size, max open files or other?

Answer (score 10):

You haven't given us much information to go on, especially about the client side.  But my suspicion is that the client side is:

- failing to setting the Content-length header (or setting it to the wrong value),
- failing to flush the output stream, and/or
- not closing the output side of the socket.

---

Mysterious.

Based on your updated question, it looks like none of the above.  Here are a couple of other possibilities:

- For some reason the client side is either locking up entirely during serialization or taking a VERY LONG TIME.
- There is a proxy between the client and server that is causing problems.
- You are experiencing load-related network problems, or network hardware problems.

---

Another possible explanation is that you have a memory leak, and that the slowdown is caused by the GC taking more and more time as you run out of memory.  This will show up in the GC logs if you have them enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think During high Concurrency, the Socket Timeout set in Tomcat is Expired and the connection is closed. The next read by Tomcat for that connection is greater than the server socket timeout specified in the server.
If you want to avoid this problem you have to increase the timeout on the server-side which is expired in your case. But not advisable.
BTW you did not give enough information. Did you increase the no of threads for connection in Tomcat? If you did, this surely would happen.